# How to create Google Project Service Account using PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-client

I am trying to create a Google project service account using the PHP client library as demonstrated https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create but I am getting this error

`Undefined property: Google\Service\Iam::$projects_serviceAccounts`.

I am not sure but it seems V2 is being loaded but I need to use V1.

Here is my method in my class

```
public function createServiceAccount()
    {
        $requestBody = new Google_Service_Iam_CreateServiceAccountRequest();

// Required: Set the account ID for the service account
        $requestBody->setAccountId($this->googleProject->project_id);

// Optional: Set additional properties for the service account
        $serviceAccount = new Google_Service_Iam_ServiceAccount();
        $serviceAccount->setDisplayName($this->googleProject->project_display_name);
        $serviceAccount->setDescription("Service account for {$this->googleProject->project_display_name}");
// Assign the service account details to the request body
        $requestBody->setServiceAccount($serviceAccount);


        $name = 'projects/' . $this->googleProject->project_id;
        return $this->service->projects_serviceAccounts->create($name, $requestBody);

    }
```

I am PHPStorm IDE that is showing me this warning

`Property 'projects_serviceAccounts' not found in \Google_Service_Iam`

Kindly help me figure out where I am going wrong.

I am creating a Laravel APP that needs to automate Google project creation as well as service accounts for these projects.

Comment: There can be a possibility that the client library you are using might have a different structure or naming convention for accessing this service. Did you install right google client library using composer require google/cloud-iam

Comment: Are you using your personal account on your computer?

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Yes, that is already installed.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am using an organization account in the app.

Comment: I have not managed to make it work to date. Kindly assist.

Comment: How did you install the google library ?

Comment: @NoahBoegli I am using Google api client composer require google/apiclient-services

Comment: Since it looks like you are using code from the V1 of their API client library, you should require the correct version with composer: `composer require google/apiclient:1.1.9`

Although updating the code to use the V2 API would be the most sensible option since the V1 is not maintained anymore.

Comment: @NoahBoegli V2 does not support creating service accounts. And if I'm wrong, kindly point me to the correct guide for creating service accounts programmatically in PHP. I shared what I found.

Comment: The version of the PHP client library and the version of the API are two different things. You can still make V1 API calls with the V2 library, it's just that the code was refactored quite a lot in the V2 library compared to the V1. So if you want to use the V2 library you're gonna have to refactor your code, or you can use the V1 library with your code and it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this line is included on your php:

```
// Autoload Composer.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Since projects_serviceAccounts is included on the following namespace based on the google-api-php-client-services repository:

```
namespace Google\Service\Iam\Resource;
```

Comment: I am still getting  ```Property 'projects_serviceAccounts' not found in \Google_Service_Iam ``` and here is all the code before my class. I am creating Laravel Service class ```<?php

namespace Google\Service\Iam\Resource;

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\GoogleProject;
use App\Models\UserProject;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Iam;
use Google_Service_Iam_CreateServiceAccountRequest;
use Google_Service_Iam_ServiceAccount;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class GoogleCloudServiceAccountApiManager
{}```

Comment: I have not managed to make it work to date. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the V2 Google PHP Client library with code that was made for the V1 version.

In V2, Google added class aliases to allow backwards compatibility with class names.
Your error seems to come from accessing an class member that does not exist in V2 anymore.

> Don't confuse the library version with the API version. With the V2 library you can still make calls to the V1 API, it's just that the code is not the same anymore.

Now coming back to your issue, if you want to make your code work as-is, you need to downgrade your Google PHP Client library:

```
composer require google/apiclient:1.1.9
```

The better option would be to migrate your code to use the V2 client library. It does not seem that creating service accounts with the PHP client is well documented outside of Google's own documentation, so you might have to do some research on what changed exactly.

The source for the `Iam` API in the V2 client library may be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/main/src/Iam).